# Mostrar checkbox seleccionado al principio de la tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo una tabla en la cual puedo seleccionar varias filas seleccionando varios checkbox usando JQuery y llenando la tabla dinamicamente, lo que necesito es que cada vez que seleccione un checkbox se muestre al principio de la tabla.

Quisera tener algo parecido a la tabla del siguiente enlace https://editor.datatables.net/examples/api/checkbox.html

Pero mi tabla esta hecha con bootstrap y no en DataTables

Esta tabla la lleno con un servicio de Node.js
Codigo HTML de tabla:

```
table#tabla1.table.table-hover(style='font-size:12px;')
thead
  tr
    th Campo 1
    th Campo 2
    th Campo 3


tbody(style='background-color:rgb(245,245,245);')
  each p in datos.p
    tr
      td.numero
          input.checkpres(data-fkp=''+p.fkp,type='checkbox', value='#{p.fkc}')
      td #{p.campo2}
      td #{p.campo3}
```

Con este codigo obtengo los checkbox seleccionados para despues manipularlos, insertarlos en una BD
Codigo JQuery.
    var seleccionados = new Array();

```
        $('.checkpres:checked').each(function() {                
            seleccionados.push([$(this).val(),$(this).attr('data-fkp')
            ]); 
        });
        console.log(seleccionados);
```

Y lo que necesito es cada vez que seleccione un checkbox se posicione al inicio de la tabla o tambien que me muestre solo los seleccionados

Esta es la tabla resultante

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes compartir tu código?

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo!

Comment: Sería bueno que miraras el código resultante en tu página (usando chrome devtools) y lo pegaras como un snippet. Así como está puesto, tendríamos que adivinar el resultado de la compilación de la plantilla